# cannot run passed Lua script to Redis: This Redis command is not allowed from scripts

Tags: redis, lua, redis-sentinel, redis-cli

I have three instances of Redis server running sentinel and a Lua script in order to let the `redis_exporter` gather the list of connected clients to the Redis server. but when I pass the script to the `redis-cli` command I get the following error:

```
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_4c6be190ef2981eda70d58ec0c959bd1ca2c5352): @user_script:10: @user_script: 10: This Redis command is not allowed from scripts
```

This is my Lua script:

```
local r = redis.call("CLIENT", "LIST")
return r
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google seems the issue is coming from the redis server itself, not the library.

The `CLIENT` command has a `no-script` flag

[image]

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/fe5aea38c35e3fc35a744ad2de73543df553ae48/src/sentinel.c